# What is the best way to get row count from a table in Cassandra?

Tags: cassandra

Is there any best way that we can get the total number of rows from the Cassandra table?

Regards,
Mani

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! A friendly reminder that this site is for getting help with coding, algorithm, or programming language problems so I voted to have your post moved to [DBA Stack Exchange](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/ask?tags=cassandra). For future reference, you should post DB admin/ops questions on https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/ask?tags=cassandra. Cheers!

Answer (score 4):

- [DatastaxBulk](https://www.datastax.com/dev/datastax-bulk-loader) is probably the easiest to install and run.
- [Apache Spark Cassandra connector](https://datastax.github.io/spark-cassandra-connector/) could be handy. Once the dataframe is loaded with `sc.cassandraTable()` you can count
- Avoid counting in your code, it does not scale as it performs a full scan of the cluster, the response time will be in seconds.
- Avoid counting with CQL `select count(*)` as you will likely hit the timeout quickly.

Answer (score 1):

#### Background

Cassandra has a built-in CQL function `COUNT()` which [counts the number of rows returned by a query](https://cassandra.apache.org/doc/latest/cassandra/cql/functions.html#count-function). If you execute an unbounded query (no filter or `WHERE` clause), it will retrieve all the partitions in the table which you can count, for example:

```
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM table_name;
```

#### Pitfalls

However, this is NOT recommended since it requires a full table scan that would query every single node which is very expensive and will affect the performance of the cluster.

It might work for very small clusters (for example, 1 to 3 nodes) with very small datasets (for example, a few thousand partitions) but in practice it would likely timeout and not return results. I've explained in detail why you shouldn't do this in [Why `COUNT()` is bad in Cassandra](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/314567/).

#### Recommended solution

There are different techniques for counting records in the database but the easiest way is to use the [DataStax Bulk Loader (DSBulk)](https://docs.datastax.com/en/dsbulk/docs/dsbulkAbout.html). It is open-source so it's free to use. It was originally designed for bulk-loading data to and exporting data from a Cassandra cluster as a scalable solution for [the cqlsh `COPY` command](https://cassandra.apache.org/doc/latest/cassandra/tools/cqlsh.html#copy-to).

DSBulk has a `count` command that provides the same functionality as the CQL `COUNT()` function but has optimisations that break up the table scan into small range queries so doesn't suffer from the same problems as brute-force counting.

DSBulk is quite simple to use and only takes a few minutes to setup. First, you need to download the binaries from [DataStax Downloads](https://downloads.datastax.com/#bulk-loader) then unpack the tarball. For details, see the [DSBulk Installation Instructions](https://docs.datastax.com/en/dsbulk/docs/install/dsbulkInstall.html).

Once you've got it installed, you can count the partitions in a table with one command:

```
$ cd path/to/dsbulk_installation
$ bin/dsbulk count -h <node_ip> -k ks_name -t table_name
```

Here are some references with examples to help you get started quickly:

- Docs - [Counting data in tables](https://docs.datastax.com/en/dsbulk/docs/dsbulkCountData.html)
- Blog - [Counting records with DSBulk](https://www.datastax.com/blog/datastax-bulk-loader-counting)
- Blog - [DSBulk Intro + Loading data](https://www.datastax.com/blog/datastax-bulk-loader-introduction-and-loading)

Comment: Hi @Erick Ramirez, do you know if the numbers returned by `dsbulk count` command accurate? Or is it just an estimate of the number of rows?  That is in case of GBs of data in the table.

Comment: A friendly note that if we respond to follow up questions in the comments, it will be a never-ending thread that's unhelpful to anyone. Instead, please ask a new question in https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/ask?tags=cassandra. Cheers!

Answer (score 1):

It is worth to mention that retrieving the exact count is discouraged in production deployments if the number of row is big because it requires a full scan with unpredictable response time and performance impact.
Even DatastaxBulk may easily take several hours, and growing with the number of rows in the table.

If what you need is just an estimated of the row count, you have some more choices:

1. if the size of a row is predictable in average, you can get the size of the space used by the table (with nodetool flush   && nodetool cfstats . or hitting wget http://localhost:10000/column_family/metrics/live_disk_space_used)
2. retrieve the estimated size directly from cassandra through the JMX MBean org.apache.cassandra.metrics:keyspace=uzzstore,name=EstimatedRowCount,scope=chunks,type=ColumnFamily
3. hit the api http://localhost:10000/column_family/metrics/estimated_row_count/yourkeyspacename:yourtablename

Note that those values are estimates updated regularly by Cassandra without our control. You can however run `nodetool flush` to force an update.

Answer (score 0):

you can simply use Count(*) to get row numbers from the table.

For example,

Syntax:

```
SELECT Count(*) 
FROM tablename;
```

and the expected output looks like this,

```
 count
-------
     4

(1 rows)
```

Comment: This command will return timeout if the table start to grow, not recommended, it is only useful for development

Answer (score 0):

You can also use cqlsh as an alternate for small tables.

**Refer this documentation**
https://www.datastax.com/blog/running-count-expensive-cassandra